# I'm seeing strange behavior in the IsUserInteractionEnabled property of Sprites, has anyone else seen this?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm writing a game with a tech tree. I want the players to research the first 4 parts of this branch before the next two techs are available. I wrote the below code and it was working backwards:

```
func applyGrayShade(to sprite: SKSpriteNode) {
    sprite.color = SKColor.gray
    sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    sprite.isUserInteractionEnabled = false 
}

func removeGrayShade(from sprite: SKSpriteNode) {
    sprite.color = SKColor.white
    sprite.colorBlendFactor = 0.0
    sprite.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

The touchesEnded does detect the sprites that I apply the gray shade to, but it does not detect them when I remove it, exactly the opposite of what I wanted to do. If I just reverse the bool in each function it works the way I want, but that doesn't make sense to me...

(this works the way I want with gray shaded sprites unavailable to touch events but made available when the remove gray shade it called, which is easily visible by the shade of the sprite)

```
func applyGrayShade(to sprite: SKSpriteNode) {
    sprite.color = SKColor.gray
    sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    sprite.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

func removeGrayShade(from sprite: SKSpriteNode) {
    sprite.color = SKColor.white
    sprite.colorBlendFactor = 0.0
    sprite.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Is this something anyone else has seen? I don't think I'm affecting it elsewhere as a search for isUserInteractionEnabled only has those 2 matches. I might just leave it backwards since it works, but I wanted to check and see what anyone might be able to help me with first. Thanks!